# Node4j get multilevel relational nodes in a subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to get nodes in a relation in a subgraph
For example:

```
A-BELONGS->B
B-BELONGS->C
C-REQUIRES->B
C-REQUIRES->H
B-REQUIRES->P
```

So I want to start at A, get all the nodes recursively which have a BELONGS relation, i.e. A,B,C, and then get the nodes which are in REQUIRES relation to those nodes but not in BELONGS relationship subgraph, i.e. H and P, but not B.  But I want to return only those nodes in a REQUIRES relation.

I've written the query like this:

```
MATCH (node:Node {name: 'A'})-[:BELONGS*]->(dep)
USING collect(node) + collect(dep) as nodes
WITH (dep)-[:REQUIRES]->(req)
return disinct req
```

Here I expect to get only P and H.  But that is not what I am getting.  What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your description your dataset looks like this:

[image]

My solution, step by step based on your problem description:

> So I want to start at A, get all the nodes recursively which have a
>   BELONGS relation, i.e. A,B,C,

```
MATCH (a:Node {name:'A'})-[:BELONGS*]->(n)
WITH a + collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as unwinded
```

> then get the nodes which are in REQUIRES relation to those nodes but
>   not in BELONGS relationship subgraph, i.e. H and P, but not B. But I
>   want to return only those nodes in a REQUIRES relation.

```
MATCH(unwinded)-[:REQUIRES]->(m)
WHERE NOT m IN nodes
RETURN m
```

The resulting Cypher query is:

```
MATCH (a:Node {name:'A'})-[:BELONGS*]->(n)
WITH a + collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as unwinded
MATCH(unwinded)-[:REQUIRES]->(m)
WHERE NOT m IN nodes
RETURN m
```

Running this query with [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) shows 22 db hits. Profiling the query described by cybersam shows 27 db hits. In a first look and a very superficial way this query seems to me a bit less costly.

Comment: Thank you that worked well.  I have started to work on Cypher, and find it quite interesting.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous syntax errors in your query. Even if we fixed those issues, the basic logic is flawed, since the `(dep)-[:REQUIRES]->(req)` pattern does not even use any of the identifiers perviously defined (`node`, `dep`, or `nodes`) and it also does not use a variable-length relationship pattern.

This should work:

```
MATCH p=(node:Node {name: 'A'})-[:BELONGS*]->(dep)
WITH NODES(p) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS n
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT n) AS ns
UNWIND ns AS nd
MATCH (nd)-[:REQUIRES*]->(req)
WHERE NOT req IN ns
RETURN DISTINCT req;
```

This query first matches all the relevant `BELONGS` paths (to any depth), deletes duplicate nodes, and collects the nodes into a single `ns` collection. Then it uses each of those nodes to get the nodes on their `REQUIRES` paths (to any depth) that are not in `ns`. Finally, it returns the distinct resulting nodes.